# Send and process <p:inputText value> along with <p:fileUpload mode="advanced">

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use p:fileUpload (modified to only allow the user to select a file) to send a file to my managed bean using ajax as i don't want JSF to validate all fields of my form every time i upload a file.

The code below works fine once i can get the file processed by *handleFileUpload* method:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" fileUploadListener="#{managedBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" widgetVar="uploadFile" process="@this"/>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="uploadFile.upload()"/>
</h:form>
```

The problem is that i need to send a text that describes the file with it. I tried to put the input text id in the fileUpload process tag but it is processed after *handleFileUpload* method.

How can i send this extra information with the file?

PS.: I'm using JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces 4.0

> Edited:
>   I noticed that the *handleFileUpload* method is invoked at the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase, while the desciption is set at the UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES phase. I tried to set the description as immediate="true", but nothing changed.

Comment: are you trying to filter the file types.??

Comment: @Dileep: i'm not trying to filter the file types.